# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined Google Map V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I know this been asked a tons of time, but I can't seem to find the correct answer to my problem.

Its actually very straight forward:

```
service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
```

Was used prior to using getDetails on its photos, so we know it actually fetches non-empty data. Next,

```
for (var i = 0; i < place.photos.length; i++) {
    ....
}
```

Afterwards I used photos length.

Please NOTE: 
It works fine, UNLESS the place actually has NO pictures to pull.... now it is throwing it off with the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

Is there a condition I can put prior to calling the place.photos.length so I can eliminate this error message?

Thanks for reading! Please help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check that `place.photos` exists first:

```
if (place.photos)
  for (var i = 0; i < place.photos.length; i++) 
    // ...
```

With that `if` check, if `place.photos` is `null` or `undefined` (probably `undefined` is the most likely, as your error indicates) then the loop won't be attempted.

Comment: Thank you... Honestly don't know why that slipped.... Thanks thanks! I'll accept it as answer.. when stackoverflow allows me to..